# onRestoreTransactionsResponse keeps returning RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm developing an Android app with in-app-billing functionality. I've followed the guidelines [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html). The only problem I'm seeing so far is that when I run the "restore transactions" command, it keeps returning `RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR`. I cannot understand why.

- The manifest does specify necessary permissions: <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
- The app is signed in debug mode, obviously.

Is this an error or is the error expected when debugging? Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to only happen in debug mode. I'll close this question.